# Change Picker Rows after window is loaded

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, picker

I'm trying to change the picker rows after the window was loaded. The picker was created in the `xml file` but when a row was attempted to be added to it an error is thrown (see below).

How do i add the picker rows once the picker is already added?

**view.xml**

```
<!-- other parent views above -->
<Picker id="languagePicker" selectionIndicator="true" useSpinner="true"
                                  width="Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth" right="0">
</Picker>
```

**view.js**

```
var languages = db.execute("SELECT * FROM language");

while(languages.isValidRow()){
    $.languagePicker.add(Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:languages.fieldByName('language')}));
    languages.next();
}
```

---

**Error Log:**

> [ERROR] The application has crashed with an uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'.
>   Reason:
>   -[NSNull rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109f28af0
>   Stack trace:
>   0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d03e4d **exceptionPreprocess + 141
>   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001096d5deb objc_exception_throw + 48
>   2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d0c48d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
>   3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c5990a ___forwarding_** + 970
>   4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c594b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>   5   UIKit                               0x0000000106466d9c -[UILabel _contentInsetsFromFonts] + 137
>   6   UIKit                               0x0000000106782a84 -[_UILabelLayer updateContentInsets] + 127
>   7   UIKit                               0x0000000106782b73 -[_UILabelLayer updateContentLayerSize] + 50
>   8   UIKit                               0x0000000106782ce1 -[_UILabelLayer layoutSublayers] + 25
>   9   QuartzCore                          0x000000010875fe70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
>   10  QuartzCore                          0x000000010875fcee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
>   11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108754475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
>   12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108781c0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
>   13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010878237c _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
>   14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c2f367 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
>   15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c2f2d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
>   16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c24f2b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
>   17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c24828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
>   18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b04bad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
>   19  UIKit                               0x00000001061f9610 UIApplicationMain + 171
>   20  ISTQB                               0x0000000104320de6 main + 310
>   21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a95192d start + 1

Comment: What happens if you don't get a row? If I read this correctly, `NSNull rangeOfCharacterFromSet` says that you're not getting a row back. Also, you have no error handler on that loop for that condition. As it's written, the code will simply ignore the `while` statement if `language` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `picker.add()` method expects an array of `PickerRow` objects. This works in my app:

```
var data = [],
    picker = Ti.UI.createPicker();
data.push(
    Ti.UI.createPickerRow({
        title: 'Row 1'
    }));
data.push(
    Ti.UI.createPickerRow({
        title: 'Row2'
    }));
picker.add(data);
```

See http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker-method-add

Comment: I accepted this answer as it is correct, however was not the solution to my problem. My problem was that I was trying to add the rows once the view was already displayed, which is not possible. TL;DR rows must be added before the view is displayed.

Comment: In my app, I dynamically create the picker and add it to the Android ActionBar as needed as the user changes between tabs. I do this all in code, rather than in the XML. Based on the error, I see you're working on iOS. But the point remains: do it in JS code rather than XML and it will work. Simply remove the picker from the UI, create a new one, and add it back to your UI with the new rows.

Comment: Yes this is true, the way I worked around it was moving the code to display the window below the code which created the picker contents.